# Blazor - User (device) geolocation

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I would like to have the option of getting the current user location on my blazor (server) app. I had tried to use two solutions
Darnton.Blazor.DeviceInterop and AspNetMonsters.Blazor.Geolocation.
With the first one, I had a problem with how to properly use that, the second one after NuGet install break the whole application ...
I will be grateful for sharing other solutions, the simpler the better

Comment: What was the problem you had with my package? Have you got any details that could help me diagnose the problem?

Comment: I need a simple example of how to use that :), assuming that I'm using the NuGet package (something like key 10 lines of code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I added such script to _Host.cshtml

```
<script>
    window.getCoords = async () => {            
        const pos = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject);
        });
        document.getElementById("SearchPoint").value = pos.coords.latitude + ', ' + pos.coords.longitude

        if ("createEvent" in document) {
            var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
            evt.initEvent("change", false, true);
            document.getElementById("SearchPoint").dispatchEvent(evt);
        }
        else
            document.getElementById("SearchPoint").fireEvent("onchange");

    };
</script>
```

and such code that calls that that from blazor component:

```
private void GetLocation()
{
    JS.InvokeAsync<(long longitude, long lattitude)>("getCoords");
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you install the Blazor Geolocation package you mentioned (Darnton.Blazor.DeviceInterop), you should be able to use the GeolocationService with a one-liner:

```
CurrentPositionResult = await GeolocationService.GetCurrentPosition();
```

I've written it all up in more detail if you want to understand what's going on inside:

https://darnton.co.nz/2020/11/29/geolocation-in-blazor/

https://darnton.co.nz/2020/11/30/geolocation-ii-position-updates/

Comment: @ bernard-darnton GeolocationService is the static class? what do I have to add as using (surprisingly vs is not suggesting anything)

Comment: There is a test project in GitHub: https://github.com/darnton/BlazorDeviceInterop/tree/master/BlazorDeviceTestRig
The page you want that does all the work is https://github.com/darnton/BlazorDeviceInterop/blob/master/BlazorDeviceTestRig/Pages/Geolocation.razor.cs

Comment: I get that error Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0016 Could not write to output file 'C:\Users\user\source\repos\BlazorDeviceInterop\Darnton.Blazor.DeviceInterop\Darnton.Blazor.DeviceInterop.xml' -- 'Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\user\source\repos\BlazorDeviceInterop\Darnton.Blazor.DeviceInterop\Darnton.Blazor.DeviceInterop.xml'.' Darnton.Blazor.DeviceInterop C:\Users\Test\BlazorDeviceInterop\Darnton.Blazor.DeviceInterop\CSC 1. And what is important C:\Users\user\source\repos\BlazorDeviceInterop\ is not my path looks like it is your one.

Comment: Also, I tried with Nuget, and that doesn't work. After instaling NuGet still, I don't have the namespace

Comment: I tried it. It works fine :)

Comment: It works fine for me too.  I instantiated the class `GeolocationService` by passing it `JSRunTime`, but I assume it works with DI as well.

Comment: @Bernard Darnton, Can I get the name of country or city by using this library?

Comment: @Nb777 Not using this library. This will just give you latitude and longitude (and maybe altitude if your device returns that data). You'll need another service to map that lat and long to a geographic location.

Answer (score 5):

This took me way too long to figure out, but I wanted to share a solution to help out others struggling. This solution works for Blazor server apps.

First add your script to the body of the _Layout.cshtml  file. It will look something like this.

```
<body>
@RenderBody()
<script>
window.getCoords = async () => {
    const pos = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject);
    });
    return [pos.coords.longitude, pos.coords.latitude];
};
<script>
</body>
```

Next you need to add the OnAfterRenderAsync method to your class. This method will make the call to your JavaScript function in _Layout.cshtml

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
  var result = await JS.InvokeAsync<JsonArray>("getCoords");
}
```

The result variable should now contain the longitude and latitude.

Notice that the return type I'm expecting is a JsonArray. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You could use JS interop to call a JS function from your Blazor component, and then use the `navigtor.geolocation` API. Your browser will automatically ask for permission when you call the geolocation API

```cs
@page "/call-js-example-1"
@inject IJSRuntime JS

    <button @onclick="GetLocation">Get location</button>

@code {

    private async Task<(long,long)> GetLocation()
    {
        ValueTuple<long,long>location = await JS.InvokeAsync<(long longitude, long lattitude)>("getLocation");
        return location;
    }
}
```

Add the function in a `<script>` tag to the `Pages/_Host.cshtml`

```html
<script>
  window.getLocation= () => {
    if(navigator.geoLocation) {
      // Do something with the navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition function
    }
  };
</script>
```

Comment: looks that  "new(await JS.InvokeAsync<(long longitude, long lattitude)>("getLocation")); " needs  c# 9.0. Is that possobie to do with C#8.0? Error: Feature 'target-typed object creation' is not available in C# 8.0. Please use language version 9.0 or greater.

Comment: I've edited the answer to work before C#9.0

Comment: unfortunately still doesn't work :(. I get such an error Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: An exception occurred executing JS interop: Null object cannot be converted to a value type.. See InnerException for more details.

Comment: I put that code to the repo https://github.com/kkrysztofczyk/GetLocation . That maybe help with problem reproducing

Answer (score 2):

You can use @Bertramp suggestion with using  JS interop. Only extending it by JS function which should return a value for interop call. This method would like something like this:

```
const getCoords = async () => {
    const pos = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject);
    });
    return [pos.coords.longitude, pos.coords.latitude];       
};
```

Comment: I think that that is the right direction still looks that it doesn't work. Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Could not find 'getCoords' in 'window'.
Error: Could not find 'getCoords' in 'window'. I push that change to https://github.com/kkrysztofczyk/GetLocation

Answer (score 0):

_Host.cshtml or index.html:

```
<script>

    window.getCoords = async () => {
        const pos = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject);
        });
        return pos.coords.latitude + ', ' + pos.coords.longitude

    };
</script>
```

razor page:

@code {
string geoLocation = string.Empty;

```
protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    geoLocation = await GetLocation();
}

private async Task<string> GetLocation()
{
    return await JS.InvokeAsync<string>("getCoords");
}
```

}

worked for me using Blazor .net 7